# Why would some HTTPS requests fail to decrypt on Fiddler, while some works ?

Tags: android, ssl, https, fiddler

Scenario: I am trying to debug an Android app by proxying requests through Fiddler.

I got FiddlerRoot certificate installed on the Android device, and the SSL decryption works for **most requests**, but for other requests I can only see the HTTPS Connect, and nothing else in the Fiddler log. I *think* it might be image requests over SSL that fails to decrypt.

I have double-checked that "Hide images" is off, etc. Images retrieved are hosted on another domain than the main API the app talks to.

What could cause this behaviour ? And how do I get the image requests to show in Fiddler ?

I am using the latest Fiddler4.

Comment: What are the target domains and what apps are the requests coming from? Some apps use Certificate Pinning, discussed in the Fiddler book, to prevent meddling by intermediaries. Others have buggy SSL implementations; see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/12/08/aes-is-not-a-valid-cipher-for-sslv3.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of tutorials on how you can intercept HTTP(s) traffic from Android using Fiddler.
Try this one: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configureforandroid

However, it will fail when you try to intercept and decrypt Android SSL traffic coming from an application, and not from a browser.

It might be that the application uses a certificate pinning – and you are probably cannot decipher this connection. Lost cause!
But more probably, **the reason is a bug in the HttpsUrlConnection pipeline implementation.**

To solve the issue, please proceed with the following steps:

1. In Fiddler click "Rules->Customize Rules";
2. Find function OnBeforeResponse in the script
3. Add following code to the function body:

   ```
   if (oSession.oRequest["User-Agent"].indexOf("Dalvik") > -1 &&
       oSession.HTTPMethodIs("CONNECT")) {
       oSession.oResponse.headers["Connection"] = "Keep-Alive";
   }
   ```
4. Save the file and restart Fiddler.